# Pandas pivot_table column header Order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, multi-index

I am trying to make a pivot table with pandas and display it.

I am using this dataset `50000 Sales Records` from https://eforexcel.com/wp/downloads-18-sample-csv-files-data-sets-for-testing-sales/

This is what it looks like

[image]

This is the code that I am using to generate the pivot table.

```
index = ['Region', 'Country']

columns = ['Item Type']

values = ['Order ID', 'Units Sold']

aggfunc = ['count', 'mean']

aggfunc = {i: j for i, j in zip(values, aggfunc)}

df_ = df[list(set(index + columns + values))]

df__ = pd.pivot_table(
    data=df_,
    index=index,
    values=values,
    columns=columns,
    aggfunc=aggfunc,
).reset_index()

df__
```

This is the result that I am getting. Here, the column headers are in the order `values -> columns`

[image]

Is there any way to get the result in the form of `columns -> values` i.e.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) with sorting `MultiIndex`:

```
df__ = pd.pivot_table(
    data=df_,
    index=index,
    values=values,
    columns=columns,
    aggfunc=aggfunc,
).swaplevel(1,0, axis=1)
 .sort_index([0,1], ascending=[True, False])
 .reset_index()
```